# JWT - Why it generates extraordinary long tokens

Tags: jwt

Everything was working fine until I decided to save the tokens (as String) with the users. The tokens were used to be 5 lines long max, and now it is keep growing every time I refresh the token. The last token I generated was 100 lines long which is not acceptable.

Every time the user logs in, I am refreshing the token.

```
module.exports.login = function(req, res){
    var user_name = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    User.findOne({username: user_name}, function(err, user){
        if(err || !user) {
            return res.json({error: "cannot find the user"});
        } else{
            user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch){
                if (err){
                    return res.json({
                        error: "passowrd doesn't match"
                    });
                }
            });
            var token = jwt.sign(user, process.env.SECRET, {
                expiresIn: 4000
            });
            console.log(token); // printing the token
        }
        if(!token){
            res.json({
                success: false,
                username: null,
                token: null
            });
        }
        else {
            user.token = token;
            User.updateUser(user._id, user, {new: true},function(err, updated_user){
                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    username: user.username,
                    token: token
                });
            });
        }
    });
};
```

All the routes are secured, and it needs to verify the token for each request.

```
module.exports.secured = function(req, res, next){
    var token;
    var username = req.body.req_username || req.headers['req_username'];
    if(username){
        User.findOne({ 'username': username }, function (err, user) {
            if (err || !user) 
                return res.json({
                    error: "cannot find the user"
                });
            else
                token = user.token;
                jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET, function(err, decode){
                    if(err){
                        res.status(500).send({
                            error: "wrong token or username"
                        });
                    } else{
                        next();
                    }
                });
        });
    } else{
        res.send({
            error: "not found"
        });
    }
};
```

I think I am not refreshing the tokens correctly.

Comment: So check what's inside and see why it grows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token should not be stored in the server because it wastes unnecessary resources.

```
 user.token = token;
 User.updateUser(user._id, user, {new: true},function(err, updated_user){
            res.json({
                success: true,
                username: user.username,
                token: token
            });
        });
```

Each time the token is refreshed you encode the `user` variable that includes the previously issued token, therefore it grows

```
var token = jwt.sign(user, process.env.SECRET, {
            expiresIn: 4000
   });
```

Remove `user.token = token`

But the main issue is that **the client MUST send the JWT in each request, not the username to recover the token**. You are verifying the token stored in user entity. It does not make sense. Change the client code to.send the JWT in the headers instead of the username `req.headers['req_username']`

Comment: you are right that token shouldn't be stored in the server, and should be sent with each API request. That is how I implemented earlier. As JWT is new to me, I decided to play with it a little. Thanks for your explanation, it now makes sense why the token is growing.